# How to get page views for a Facebook page via GraphAPI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am an Admin for a Facebook page and need to get the number of users that go to the page in the most granular level possible (If I could get it for each minute that would be great).
However I am unable to get this information. I can get other information such as shares, likes etc via the GraphAPI.

[image: GraphAPI results]

Inside the GraphAPI whenever I try and get page_views I get no data returned and the "paging" section contains a "previous" and "next" link. The "previous" and "next" links then return no data and a "paging" section which includes "previous" and "next" links with updated "since" and "until" values in the URL.

I have also tried inputting the "since" and "until" times in yyyy-mm-dd format and I still get the same results, no data and a "previous" and "next" link in the "paging" section.

Is it possible to get "page views" or something similar via GraphAPI?

Comment: What metrics you can get, is described in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/insights And you will of course need to use an access token for either a user that has admin access to the page, or a page access token (for any metrics that are not publicly available.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insights metrics that give you the data in this area are:

page_impressions_by_city_unique - The number of people who have seen any content associated with your Page by city
page_views - Page views
page_views_unique - Page Views from users logged into Facebook
page_views_login - Page Views from users logged into Facebook
page_views_login_unique - Page Views from users logged into Facebook